# When is a product of two two-parameter Mittag-Leffler functions a Mittag-Leffler function?

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

I am studying properties of the **two-parameter** Mittag-Leffler function.
$$  E_{\alpha,\beta}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\beta)}.$$
I am particularly interested in recurrences and relations, such as the duplication formulas.
However, I am seeking some relation in which **a product of two two-parameter Mittag-Leffler functions is a Mittag-Leffler function**, does anyone know something about this? Maybe about powers, but not necessarily.

This is a repost of this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402681/when-is-a-product-of-two-two-parameter-mittag-leffler-functions-a-mittag-leffler.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You got (and accepted) an answer on Math Overflow. Does that mean that the question is obsolete here?

Comment: @MartinR Yes and no... Yes, I've gotten an answer on Math Overflow, but I cannot pin as duplicate, because the link is not here and the sytem does not accepted... And no because if someone would like to say some more thing, it's welcome...! Thank you for attention!